# How do I use FormData from JavaScript Code Module context?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, form-data

How do I use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) from a [JavaScript Code Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using)?

```
new FormData();
```

gives:

> FormData is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because JavaScript Code Modules do not have a normal browser context, I sometimes get around this by passing in a `window`, `document`, or whatever object might pertain to what I needed (e.g., passing in the `window` or `FormData` object when you invoke a method built inside your module).

However, I see this concern has already been raised by someone and there is a way around it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672690#c4

```
var formData = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/files/formdata;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMFormData);
```

I believe you can always find such class/interface equivalents of browser context items, unless you need to grab a specific `window` or `document`.